# Insert data in to a table based on query that uses data in other tables other than what needs to be inserted

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My problem involves copying data into multiple tables from one cdv file. My tables are

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS apt_info 
    (
house_number varchar(10) NOT NULL,
block varchar(3) NOT NULL,
owner_id int,
KEY owner_id (owner_id),
CONSTRAINT apt_owner FOREIGN KEY (owner_id) REFERENCES owner_info(owner_id),
tenant_id INT,
KEY tenant_id (tenant_id),
CONSTRAINT apt_tenant FOREIGN KEY (tenant_id) REFERENCES tenant_info(tenant_id),
CONSTRAINT apt_id PRIMARY KEY (block, house_number)

other columns storing different apt related values
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS owner_info 
(
owner_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname varchar(80),
lastname varchar(80),

other column storing different owner related values
);
```

I have a CSV file that has apartment details including owner name in each row. Since I want to store owner info in a different table and same owner may have multiple apartments, I created a temp table as

```
Title,FirstName,Last Name,block,house_number,Sq. Foot
Mr,Debraj,Gupta,A,101,1709
,Laxman, ,A,102,1463
,Laxman, ,A,103,1418
Mr,T A,Padmanabhan,A,104,1821
```

I created a `temp_owner_info` table with fields for each column and used `LOAD DATA` to insert these records. Then I populated `owner_info` table with

```
INSERT INTO owner_info (title, firstname, lastname)
SELECT DISTINCT title, firstname, lastname 
FROM temp_owner_info;
```

Now I want to populate `apt_info` table with block, house_number, sq_ft details from `temp_owner_info` and owner_id from `owner_info` table

How do I do that? The owner_id I want can be obtained by comparing first name and last name values. I am new to SQL and unable to write the select statement that is needed to compare values of multiple tables.

i thought its easier to add owner_id column to the temp_owner_info table and get the auto generated values from owner_info before using the information to populate apt_info
however the below query ends up with the error message

update temp_owner_info tmp
set owner_id = o.owner_id
from owner_info as o
where 
tmp.firstname = o.firstname and
tmp.lastname = o.lastname;

error message: Error code 1064, SQL state 42000: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from owner_info as o
where 
tmp.firstname = o.firstname and
tmp.lastname = o.las' at line 3
Line 1, column 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Insert into apt_info (block, house_number, sq_ft, owner_id)
SELECT toi.block, toi.house_number, toi.sq_ft,
  (select oi.owner_id from owner_info oi 
    where oi.firstname = toi.firstname
    and oi.lastname = toi.lastname) owner_id
from temp_owner_info toi
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I am trying to figure out how to declare instances of tables (the way you have used toi and oi). i always end up with errors. Is there someplace i can learn the correct format of this?. Would be great if i get some pointers. Thanks in advance Chetana